# Express route not found on redirect but route exists

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So in my express server I have redirection to a route `/chat` like this

```
if (!user) {
            res.json(info);
        } else {
            req.logIn(user, function() {
                res.redirect('/chat');
            })
        }
```

I' m registring my route like this

```
app.use('/chat', require('./routes/chat'));
```

and in my routes/chat file

```
import * as express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

// Chat Page
router.get('/chat', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => res.render('chat'));

module.exports = router;
```

What I want to do is for it to redirect to the route which display React component but it returns `GET http://localhost:3000/chat 404 (Not Found) Error: Request failed with status code 404`

If I just paste the path `http://localhost:3000/chat` and go the page my component shows up.

So I'm not really sure what to do in this situation and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
router.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => res.render('chat'));
```

You have already define `/chat` path.

Comment: This way I'm getting ```No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.```

Comment: what template engine you use? ejs, pug??

Comment: I don't. I use react on frontend

Answer (score 0):

By app.use() you can define an application-level middleware to an instance of the app object.

So, you define a middleware on `/chat` route in chat.js

```
app.use('/chat', require('./routes/chat'));
```

Now in chat.js you can do this:

```
router.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => res.render('chat'));
```

it resolved as /chat.

even if you want to define another route as `/chat/room` you can do this in chat.js

```
router.get('/room', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => res.render('chat'));
```